# How to display all the document library and it's sub folders and the file count in C# console application?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, document-library, console-application

In SharePoint 2013 site. I have many documents library and many folders inside document library.

I'm trying to display all these documents library and folders in console application.

Please suggest something

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
 {
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite("http://pc5"))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                //Get the collection of all documents library
                SPListCollection docLibraryColl = oWeb.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);

                foreach (SPList list in docLibraryColl)
                {
                    //Display Document libarry name 

                    Console.Write(list.Title);


                    if (list != null)
                    {
                        foreach (SPListItem item in list.Folders)
                        {
                            //Display Folder from document library
                            Console.WriteLine("Folders from" + list.Title+ "are as follows");
                            Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
                        }
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thanks, but am getting error on using SPSite,SPWeb, and SPList wht to do ?

Comment: Have you added Reference Microsoft.SharePoint

Comment: Yes i added the reference

Comment: What is error message ?

Comment: a red under line unable to run

Comment: can you send me the screen shot of message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49595/discussion-between-akshay-dattatray-nangare-and-jishink).

Comment: i Need the client object model , that's why i get error sorry